# MySQL query in PHP with '&' returns different results than phpMyAdmin does

Tags: php, mysql

Records which contain an ampersand (`&`) are not returned by MySQL (connected to via PHP), but the same query works fine in phpMyAdmin. I am not sure if it is a collate/charset problem. Here is the sample query:

```sql
SELECT distinct(pcs.shop_name) AS shopName 
FROM shops AS ps 
LEFT JOIN category_shop AS cs 
   ON ps.shop_id = cs.shop_id 
WHERE 1=1 
   AND (ps.shop_name LIKE '%P&G%') 
   AND ps.is_active!=2 
ORDER BY ps.shop_display_name ASC
```

The `shop_name` I am trying to search for is `P&G`.

Comment: What's the encoding of the database, table & field? Are you using the same encoding for your connection from PHP?

Comment: Is this the *exact* query you use even in your PHP code?

Comment: Daan, The encoding is "latin1_swedish_ci" for table and shop_name field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (i guess You are using GET to submit a form if You have problem with ampersand):

```
$shop_name = urlencode('P&G');
```

on Your page for that field values (this means You call urlencode for every field value when generating form). Then after a GET is done, simply do:

```
$shop_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['shop_name']);
$query = "SELECT distinct(pcs.shop_name) as shopName 
    FROM shops AS ps 
    LEFT JOIN category_shop AS cs ON ps.shop_id = cs.shop_id 
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND (ps.shop_name LIKE '%{$shop_name}%') 
        AND ps.is_active!=2 
    ORDER BY ps.shop_display_name ASC";
```

Does this work for You?